# 'Birthdate vs birthday'- I know three other people who share my birthdate

Tags: meaning, word-choice, phrases, ambiguity

> We say birthday and not birthdate

Generally, [birthplace](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/birthplace) is used for place of birth but not birthdate for date of birth.

What is the reason that ***birthday scores over*** ***birthdate*** when it comes to usage.

- > I know three other people who share my birthday
  >
  > vs
  >
  > I know three other people who share my birthdate

Comment: "Birthday" communicates and connotes much more than "the date on which I was born". For one thing, you only have *one* birthplace, but *many* birthdays (hopefully!). A birthday is a celebration, and anniversary, a cause for anticipation or dread; it's a time for everyone who loves you to think about you and be glad that you were born. In other words, it's a *big day*! Beyond that, try not to expect language to *make sense*, and certainly don't expect it to be perfectly consistent. BTW, you might like to check out another site: http://ell.stackexchange.com .

Comment: Three people can share a birthday or birthdate.            If I specifically want to know when someone was born, I would ask "What is your date of birth ? If I want to wish someone, I would say "Happy birthday! Your birthday is the anniversary of your birth, it is just the day and month. Your date of birth will include the full year.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Like the bureaucratic, *Date of Birth*,  ***birthdate*** includes the year. Baryshnikoff (Jan 27, 1948) and Mozart (Jan 27, 1756) share a *birthday* but not a *birthdate.*

I have met many people who were born on the same day of the year as me, but only one who also was born the same year.  I did refer to her as having the same *birthdate* as me.  (American English)

Answer (score -1):

A birth-date is the DATE of BIRTH, birth-day is the DAY of BIRTH. Leap-year babies (leapers) have a birth-day every year, but only have a birth-date every 4 years (Feb. 29). It seems like I am the only one who gets this whenever people say happy birth-day to a 40 year old and say they are only 10 when they are actually 40 years old and 10 leap-years old, if they're born on Feb. 29.